# How do I override the Rails devise gem default SMTP to send via an API instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

By default the Rails Devise gem sends emails through SMTP, but in my case I need to send them through an API instead. What's a good way to override Devise's defaults?

I'm thinking if I could knew how to generate the email texts based on `resource_params` I would be able to use that in `users/passwords_controller.rb` for example to send out the emails within the `create` method.

Comment: Are you trying to switch to an email as a service platform? Most offer SMTP as well.

Comment: I need to use API, not their SMTP, ideally.

Comment: Which API you are using ?

Comment: Freshdesk's API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this, use custom Mailer

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

with stubbed deliver method to avoid send't it through SMTP, with you API logic inside devise mailer methods, each Devise module has own mailer methods

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/search?q=send_devise_notification&unscoped_q=send_devise_notification